# crystal reports not displaying

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I am trying to use crystal report on my demo application.Data is properly binding to report but, when used crystal report viewer to view on web page it does'nt display any data.In mozilla ,chrome it does'nt give any error but the report is also not displayed.When i use internet explorer,it gives error "javascript runtime error bobj is undefined".I m not even using iis.It is not displaying on local asp.net development server also.It do not even display empty crystal report viewer also.What settings should be done to get rid of this problem? Help me...

Answer (score 0):

try to re install crystal report app